# jqGrid sorting on dropdown column when column is filtered

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

In my jqGrid, I have columns which have dropdown options(nexus:yes, no; shipping:yes, no). Sorting and filtering work by itself, however if I filter my grid by nexus(yes is selected from the dropdown) and try sorting my result by stateid or name, my grid does not do anything. I debugged the code and I saw that jqGrid makes an ajax call and query returns correctly, however when I look at the response, I see that it is HTTP 200 OK, but the result does not contain any data. All sorting and filtering happens in the code behind. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: It seems that you use **server side** sorting and filtering. In the case the origin of the problem should be in your server code.

Comment: These columns' datatype was boolean, changing them to int actually made it work. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome! You solved the problem yourself.